# How to make bullet points aligned in list

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am doing a little exercise where I have to copy [this](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10998095/Screenshots/sc-qh9z6m-v8.png)

I am having some trouble to align the bullets like he does. My problem is that my content is aligned bot not the bullets.

[Here it is](https://jsfiddle.net/7mr6shha/)

**My HTML:**

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3" id="left-box">
            <h3 class="text-center">Some Favorites</h3>
            <ul class="text-center">
                <li>Celery Root</li>
                <li>Spaghetti Squash</li>
                <li>Killer Mushrooms</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-9">
            <h1>Wild & Wacky Vegetables</h1>
            <p>Normally, both your asses would be dead as fucking fried chicken, but you happen to pull this shit while I'm in a transitional period so I don't wanna kill you, I wanna help you. But I can't give you this case, it don't belong to me. Besides, I've already been through too much shit this morning over this case to hand it over to your dumb ass.</p>
            <p>My money's in that office, right? If she start giving me some bullshit about it ain't there, and we got to go someplace else and get it, I'm gonna shoot you in the head then and there. Then I'm gonna shoot that bitch in the kneecaps, find out where my goddamn money is. She gonna tell me too. Hey, look at me when I'm talking to you, motherfucker. You listen: we go in there, and that nigga Winston or anybody else is in there, you the first motherfucker to get shot. You understand?
            You think water moves fast? You should see ice. It moves like it has a mind. Like it knows it killed the world once and got a taste for murder. After the avalanche, it took us a week to climb out. Now, I don't know exactly when we turned on each other, but I know that seven of us survived the slide... and only five made it out. Now we took an oath, that I'm breaking now. We said we'd say it was the snow that killed the other two, but it wasn't. Nature is lethal but it doesn't hold a candle to man.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

**My CSS**:

```
 #left-box{
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    margin-top: 2%;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

ul{
    padding-left: 0;
}

ul li{
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a complete working example. You can use http://jsfiddle.net for that (or use snippets here inside stackoverflow).

Comment: Added the fiddle. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the centering of the text inside your `ul` element:

```
        <h3 class="text-center">Some Favorites</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>Celery Root</li>
            <li>Spaghetti Squash</li>
            <li>Killer Mushrooms</li>
        </ul>
```

Here is a working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/m782jg44/1/

If you want to align the entire list - you will have to set it's width and center the container (the `ul` element, not the text).

Here is a working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/m782jg44/2/

Comment: It's not aligned in the center of the column

Comment: The image you provided is not aligned as well. Note that if you want to align it you will need to set the width of the container, and align that container to the center (and not the text).

Comment: There is a better solution to this problem, you don't have to set width because it can be extended in greater width or less , instead of using `width: 140px`, you can use `display: table` property.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/7mr6shha/1/) is your updated code

```css
#left-box{
 background-color: whitesmoke;
 margin-top: 2%;
 border: 1px solid white;
 border-radius: 3px;

}

ul{
 padding-left: 0;
}

ul li{
 list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<body>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

 <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3" id="left-box">
                <h3 class="text-center">Some Favorites</h3>
   <ul>
    <li>Celery Root</li>
    <li>Spaghetti Squash</li>
    <li>Killer Mushrooms</li>
   </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9"><h1>Wild & Wacky Vegetables</h1>
   <p>Normally, both your asses would be dead as fucking fried chicken, but you happen to pull this shit while I'm in a transitional period so I don't wanna kill you, I wanna help you. But I can't give you this case, it don't belong to me. Besides, I've already been through too much shit this morning over this case to hand it over to your dumb ass.</p>
   <p>My money's in that office, right? If she start giving me some bullshit about it ain't there, and we got to go someplace else and get it, I'm gonna shoot you in the head then and there. Then I'm gonna shoot that bitch in the kneecaps, find out where my goddamn money is. She gonna tell me too. Hey, look at me when I'm talking to you, motherfucker. You listen: we go in there, and that nigga Winston or anybody else is in there, you the first motherfucker to get shot. You understand?
   You think water moves fast? You should see ice. It moves like it has a mind. Like it knows it killed the world once and got a taste for murder. After the avalanche, it took us a week to climb out. Now, I don't know exactly when we turned on each other, but I know that seven of us survived the slide... and only five made it out. Now we took an oath, that I'm breaking now. We said we'd say it was the snow that killed the other two, but it wasn't. Nature is lethal but it doesn't hold a candle to man.</p>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove class text-center from ul tag and try to change ul tag directly or using another class with this style.

```
ul {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/lavdimxhelii/p93ccj07/